# Same query provides different results in SQL Server client and JDBC client

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, mssql-jdbc

I'm using SQL Server in my project and I am trying to retrieve entries in a table between two timestamps. The schema of the table is given below:

```
CREATE TABLE ENTRY (
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    NAME VARCHAR (2000),
    USER_ID VARCHAR (31) NOT NULL,
    ADDED_TIME DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

I need to get the entries that are added after a particular timestamp and the current timestamp. For this I have tried the below mentioned query:

```
SELECT * FROM ENTRY WHERE
ADDED_TIME>$parameter1 AND ADDED_TIME<$currentTime ORDER BY ADDED_TIME DESC

SELECT * FROM ENTRY WHERE
ADDED_TIME>'12/03/2020 12:13:08.583' AND ADDED_TIME<'12/03/2020 13:36:05.159' ORDER BY ADDED_TIME DESC
```

When executing this query directly on the SQL client, I got all the expected results. But when I execute the same query from Java JDBC client, the `resultset` contain entry which has ADDED_TIME equals to parameter1.

Here is the Java code of the client:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM ENTRY WHERE ADDED_TIME>? AND ADDED_TIME<? ORDER BY ADDED_TIME DESC";
Date to = new Date();
PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
statement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(Long.parseLong("1606977788583")));
statement.setTimestamp(2, new Timestamp(to.getTime()));
ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery();
```

The resultset contain entry that has `ADDED_TIME` as `1606977788583`. It is only returned if I execute it using Java JDBC client. What could be the possible reason for this.

Appreciate any help on this,

Comment: I'm not so sure those queries are the same; one uses sting literals for dates where as the other appears to use date and time parameters. They are by definition different. When using string literals, for dates, you need to ensure you use ambiguous ones as well; in SQL server that's `yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn`.

Comment: You need to give example data, and write your example code in such a way as to be comparing apples to apples.

Comment: By the way, the `DATETIME` type in MS SQL Server does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a specific point on the timeline. That type is a date and a time-of-day but lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So comparing such values with the current moment is suspect. To track moments, you should be using type `datetimeoffset` in MS SQL Server, a type akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the JDBC Java client gave different result is:

There are two data types that support date-time format in SQL Server:

1. DATETIME
2. DATETIME2

The data type of the column `ADDED_TIME` is DATETIME. But when setting the parameter using `PreparedStatement.setTimestamp()` the parameter implicitly gets mapped to **DATETIME2** type. There seems to be no way to set it as **DATETIME** type when using `setTimestamp()` method. This is being discussed in [1] as well.

Fixed it by correcting the query as follows:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM ENTRY WHERE 
              ADDED_TIME> CONVERT(DATETIME, ?) AND 
              ADDED_TIME< CONVERT(DATETIME, ?) 
              ORDER BY ADDED_TIME DESC";
```

[1] https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc/issues/443

Comment: The `setTimestamp` method is Java is a part of the terrible date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java, now legacy. Use only *java.time* classes in modern Java, with `PreparedTransaction::setObject` method.